# Material-ui Autocomplete - OnChange is blocking other features to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, onchange

I am trying to work with the Autocomplete component,

this is my code:

```
 <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={ownerOptions2}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      filterSelectedOptions={true}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue);
 ** ****props.onSelectionChange(newValue)***** **
            }}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="label" placeholder="" />
      )}
    />
```

Without the "onChange" part, it's working great.
But I need to save and do something with the selected values, (is there another way to do it?).

When I'm adding the "onChange" part and run there a function from props, neither the filterSelectedOptions nor the checkbox is working.

What is the right way to do it?

Tnx

Comment: how did you fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (based on https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states ) is that if you specify onChange or value you need to supply both (and therefore handle the state of value yourself).

Comment: A more specific problem :

The onChange does working, but,
if iI trying to use a function from props inside it, so the filterSelectedOptions is not working.

any ideas?

Comment: What does that function do? If it changes the state of the parent component you might need to manage the state of this Autocompomplete from the parent component.